# Google шрифты подключаются через раз

Tags: css, google-fonts

Подключаю шрифты через CSS @import, вот так:

```
@import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cormorant+Garamond:700';
```

Использую, вот так:

```
h2, h3 {
  font-family: 'Cormorant Garamond', serif;
}
```

Но шрифты, примерно, один раз из 10 не подключаются, браузер пытается их подключить, но безуспешно, после чего в консоли светятся вот такие ошибки:

[image: Ошибки в консоли]

Что мною делается не так?

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так:

```
@import url("//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cormorant+Garamond:700");
```

Два отличия:

1. Уточним url() при импорте - можно импортировать без него, но с ним надежнее, особенно в случае с препроцессорами (Sass Stylus Less);
2. Убираем протокол. Позволяем сайту взаимодействовать с api гугла по тому же протоколу, по которому пользователь взаимодействует с сайтом.

Comment: Изначально, я с url() и юзал, но последний шрифт мне гугл без него дал, я решил убрать. Хорошо, сейчас попробую один в один как Вы посоветовали, по прошествии некоторого времени, отпишусь.

Comment: Проблема стала чуть реже проявляться, но не пропала полностью -=((